# Why is bind9 not responding to reverse zones to anyone?

Tags: linux, bind, reverse-dns, ptr-record

There is BIND 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian (Extended Support Version) <id:998753c> for the local network, it works as a caching server and holds several domain zones.

Recursive requests are allowed only from the internal network, from the external network the server must respond only to zones that are known to it.

The problem is that the server does not respond to reverse zones from the external network, while direct zones work properly from any network.

```
# cat /var/log/named.log
...
Jul 13 08:41:08  named[14909]: client @0x7f968c0d64e0 89.209.65.11#49410 (220.X.X.109.in-addr.arpa): query (cache) '220.X.X.109.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN' denied
...
```

Configuration

```
# cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options
options {

        notify yes;

        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        allow-query { any; };
        allow-recursion { LAN; };
        allow-query-cache { LAN; };
        allow-transfer { 172.19.0.2; };

        dnssec-validation yes;

        listen-on { 172.19.0.1; 109.X.X.X; };

        listen-on-v6 { none; };

        version "unknown";

};
```

```
# cat /etc/bind/named.conf
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

acl "LAN" {
        INTERNAL_NETWORK;
        localhost;
        localnets;
};

zone "fibernet.X.X" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/fibernet.X.X.zone";
};

zone "216/29.X.X.109.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/216_29.X.X.109.in-addr.arpa";
};

zone "128/26.X.X.188.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/128_26.X.X.188.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

```
:~# cat /etc/bind/216_29.X.X.109.in-addr.arpa
$ORIGIN 216/29.X.X.109.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 21600
@       IN      SOA     ns1.fibernet.X.X. max.fibernet.X.X. (
                                2023071001
                                6H
                                2H
                                2W
                                1D)

@               NS      ns1.fibernet.X.X.
@               NS      ns2.fibernet.X.X.

220             PTR     mail.fibernet.X.X.
218             PTR     fibernet.X.X.

219             PTR     bras1.fibernet.X.X.
```

If I add in named.conf.options file

```
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-query-cache { any; };
        allow-recursion { any; };
```

Reverse zones are starting to work, but I don't need recursive requests from the external network.

How to correctly configure bind9 for my task?

Comment: It seems to respond recursively from the cache... did you `rndc reload`?

Comment: Yes, of course, I did rndc reload but it is still silent from the external network to reverse zones if allow-recursion { LAN; }; allow-query-cache { LAN; };